# Convert JSON containing JS function definition to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert JSON containing JS function definitions

```
{  
    "a1": "5",  
    "b1": "10",  
    "c1": "function(param1,param2) { return param1 +param2}"  
}
```

to a JavaScript object containing those functions (and not a string with the definition):

```
{  
    a1: 5,  
    b1: 10,  
    c1: function(param1,param2) { return param1 + param2}  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: the `"a1"` quotes do not matter, but the string for that should be replaced with `parseInt()` for that value to obtain an integer value, but the JSON string really should by `"a1":5`.  Evil eval for the function?

Comment: **NOT a duplicate!** The guy wants the `c1` value to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a **reviver function** to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). This lets you apply custom logic to parsed values.

In this function you can test whether a the value starts with the pattern `function(...) {`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str, function(k, v) {

    if (/^\s*function\s*\([^)]*\)\s*{/.test(v)) {
        try {
            // using the Function constructor to evaluate the function
            // definition in global scope
            return Function('return ' + v)();
        }
        catch() {
            return v; // maybe not a JS function definition after all
        }
    }
    return v;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/63eEJ/)

Of course you could also just iterate over the resulting object and apply the same logic after the parsing, but using a reviver function is easier if you have nested objects/arrays.

Note that this is a very simple test and would only work for anonymous functions. If you have named functions, you have to adjust the expression accordingly. But this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

using the JS function [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
var myobj = JSON.parse("{\"a1\": \"5\",  \"b1\": \"10\",  \"c1\": \"function(param1,param2) { return param1 +param2}\"  }");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two step: parse the json, and promote the function source code to a function:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFromAjax);
jsonObj.c1 = eval(jsonObj.c1);
```

Comment: hallo, by eval() "function(param1,param2) { return param1 + param2}" is still with quotes :(, TXH

Comment: @adoweb: No it's not?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that converts a json string containing a function back to a json object with a valid function declaration.

var jsonstring = "{\"schema\": {\"title\": \"User Feedback\", \"description\":\"so\", \"type\":\"object\", \"properties\":{\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}," +
                        "\"options\":{ \"form\":{\"attributes\":{}, \"buttons\":{ \"submit\":{ \"title\":\"It\", \"click\":\"function(){alert('hello');}\" }}} }}";

var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonstring);

```
function Iterate(data)
{
      jQuery.each(data, function (index, value) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            Iterate(value);
        }
        else {
            if (value.indexOf("function()") > -1)
                data[index] = eval("(" + value + ")");
        }
    });

};

Iterate(jsonData);
```

In this case 
jsonData.options.form.buttons.submit.click();